# How to rearrange rows and column in R

Tags: r, sorting, combinations

Please help to rearrange rows and cloumns
.
I have two tables (mat and mat1)
The table 1 is mat

```
mat <- matrix("", 5, 7)
mat[c(1),] <- sample(c("AA", "AG", "GG", "--"), 7, TRUE)
mat[c(2),] <- sample(c("AA", "AT", "TT", "--"), 7, TRUE)
mat[c(3),] <- sample(c("CC", "CG", "GG", "--"), 7, TRUE)
mat[c(4,5),] <- sample(c("CC", "CG", "GG", "--"), 7, TRUE)
colnames(mat)= c("Line_1", "Line_2", "Line_3", "Line_4", "Line_5", "Line_6", "Line_7")
row.names(mat)= c("Marker_1", "Marker_2", "Marker_3", "Marker_4", "Marker_5")
```

The table 2 is mat1

```
mat1<-matrix(c("1", "1","3","8","10", 2.3, 4.3, 45.5, 102.8, 74.8), nrow = 5)
row.names(mat1)= c("Marker_1", "Marker_2", "Marker_3", "Marker_4", "Marker_5")
colnames(mat1)= c("Linkage_Group", "Map_Position")
```

I used cbind to combine two tables

```
mat2 <- cbind(mat, mat1)
```

however I need to rearrage the data by comparing each Lines and get the result with an additaional column of comparison in a following format. If teh marker data matches it is 'Mono, if one or both has missing it is 'Mis', if not match it is 'Poly'

```
Comparison           Marker  Linkage_Group Map_Position   LineX1  LineX2   Mon/Poly
Line_1/Line_2       "Marker_1"      "1"     "2.3"       "AA"        "--"      Mis
Line_1/Line_3       "Marker_1"      "1"     "2.3"       "AA"        "TT"      Poly
Line_1/Line_4       "Marker_1"      "1"     "2.3"       "AA"        "TT"      Poly
Line_1/Line_5       "Marker_1"      "1"     "2.3"       "AA"        "AT"      Poly
Line_1/Line_6       "Marker_1"      "1"     "2.3"       "AA"        "--"      Mis
Line_1/Line_7       "Marker_1"      "1"     "2.3"       "AA"        "AA"      Mono

.
.
.
```

There will be 21 line combinations for the above example.

There are many R gurus here...Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps:

Combination of column names `Line`. 
 Use `grep` to find the pattern in column names

```
indx <- combn(colnames(mat2)[grep("Line", colnames(mat2))], 2)
```

split the column name indx by columns of indx so that each list element is a    combination of two columns

```
  res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(indx, col(indx)), function(x) {
 m1 <- mat2[, c("Linkage_Group", "Map_Position", x)] ##subset mat2 
#compare the concerned columns rowwise  
m2 <- cbind(Comparison = paste(x, collapse = "/"), Marker = row.names(m1), m1, 
    `Mon/Poly` = apply(m1[, 3:4], 1, function(x) ifelse(any(grepl('--', x)), "Mis",
 ifelse(x[1] == x[2], "Mono", "Poly"))))
}))
```

order if needed

```
res1 <- res[order(res[,"Marker"], res[,"Linkage_Group"], res[,"Map_Position"]),]

tail(res1,3)
#       Comparison      Marker     Linkage_Group Map_Position Line_1 Line_2
# Marker_5 "Line_5/Line_6" "Marker_5" "10"          "74.8"       "--"   "--"  
# Marker_5 "Line_5/Line_7" "Marker_5" "10"          "74.8"       "--"   "--"  
# Marker_5 "Line_6/Line_7" "Marker_5" "10"          "74.8"       "--"   "--"  
#         Mon/Poly
# Marker_5 "Mis"   
# Marker_5 "Mis"   
# Marker_5 "Mis"
```

BTW: It would be better to store these in data.frame

Comment: akrun: there is a small issue in the code as it is not differenciating correctly when both lines has '--'. It should be classified as 'Mis' not as 'Mono' in the last column